# How to set models choices dynamicly in Django

Tags: python, django

First please have a look at my code below:

```
Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,null=False, blank=True)
if Porject is 'A':
    Owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=**owner_set_A**)
else:
    Owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=**owner_set_B**)
```

So the owner choices should switch from owner_set_A to B, it depense on the value of Project.
Who i tell me how can i do this,
Thanks for Timmy's reply, but what should i do in models.Model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,null=False, blank=True)
    if Porject is 'A':
        Owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=**owner_set_A**)
    else:
        Owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=**owner_set_B**)
```

Is there a way to get the project field value?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two separate fields. The field just holds the data, you instead need to filter what [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) the user is presented with in their form. If you are using the django admin for example, you can do something like (untested)

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
         super(MyModel, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
         if self.fields['project'].foo == "bar":
             self.fields['owner'].choices = ((0, "X"), (1, "Y"),...)
         else:
             self.fields['owner'].choices = ((0, "A"), (1, "B"),...)

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Comment: Hi Timmy, please see my comments

Comment: I read your update. The point is that you shouldn't try to do this in the models, it's not the correct place for it. You don't have two separate *types* of field, you have two different *sets of data* that go in the field. For that reason, you should filter what values can be saved in the field at a different layer such as the Form layer or even Template layer